# Cast the value in a Map

Tags: java, google-app-engine, casting

I am using memcache (Google App Engine) and use getAll() to retrieve several cache entries in a batch. My cache entries are:

```
private Map<String, Set<Long>> cacheEntries; // key: String, value: Set<Long>
```

getAll() returns Object as value (because it doesn't know I have cached a Set previously), here is the signature:

```
<T> java.util.Map<T,java.lang.Object> getAll(java.util.Collection<T> collection);
```

In my code I go:

```
cacheEntries = cache.getAll(keys); // cache is the MemcacheService, keys is a Collection of String
```

which obviously fails because Object is returned and Set is expected. So I tried to cast the map like this:

```
cacheEntries = (Map<String, Set<Long>>) cache.getAll(keys);
```

but the compiler tells me

```
Incompatible types, cannot cast Map<String, Object> to Map<String, Set<Long>
```

It is clear why: I am trying to cast the whole Map while I really need to cast the value in each map entry.

Sure I could solve this by iterating over the Map and casting each value separately, but I'd like to know if there is a better way to achieve that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can cast it to raw `Map` before casting to `Map<String, Set<Long>>`:

```
cacheEntries = (Map<String, Set<Long>>)(Map)cache.getAll(keys);
```

You could also use `Map<String, ?>` if you don't want the raw type warning.